# Unable to capture records name , price and rating and image in Requests Python

Tags: python, json, selenium, beautifulsoup, request

Exception occur when printing the productname, product size price and rating
here is the link from which i want to extract the details.

```
import requests
import time

from requests.models import Response


params = ((
    'url','/continental-80-shoes/G27707.html'),
    ('sitePath', 'us'),)
 


headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36'
}

response = requests.get('https://www.adidas.com/api/metadata/pdp',params=params,headers=headers)

for item in response.json()['metadata']:

    itemRes = requests.get('https://www.adidas.com/api/search/product/'+item['productId'],headers=headers) 
    print(item['productId'],item['name'],item['price'],item['rating])
```

Comment: your item does not contain the key "productId" i contains the keys  ```dict_keys(['title', 'metadata_tags', 'url', 'hreflangs', 'internalLinks'])```

Comment: So please tell me which algorithm that i used  to extract all  the details to print

Comment: I cant with the info or data you have supplied

Comment: so what the way should i use to get right hit

Comment: does not look like ther is one endpoint for all that info, You'll have to dig deaper in the apis and maybe combine sevral endpoints

Comment: from this endpoint im able to get the id and the price but no rating: https://www.adidas.com/api/search/product/G27707

Comment: so there is no way to get whole page endpoint

Comment: ok i found a sloution for this scraping the actual site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to scrape the adidas site and use regex:

```py
import requests
import re

endpoint = "https://www.adidas.com.au/continental-80-shoes/G27707.html"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/86.0.4240.198 Safari/537.36'
}
response = requests.get(endpoint, headers = headers)
data = response.text

pricereg = r"(?<=\"price\":)(.*)(?=,\")"
namereg = r"(?<=\"name\":)(.*)(?=,\"co)"
ratingreg= r"(?<=\"ratingValue\":)(.*)(?=,\"reviewCou)"

price = re.search(pricereg, data, re.MULTILINE).group()
name = re.search(namereg, data, re.MULTILINE).group()
rating = re.search(ratingreg, data, re.MULTILINE).group()

print(f"name {name}, rating {rating}, price {price}")
```